# Running PL/SQL script in PHP

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a script in PL/SQL , that drop some tables , sequences , triggers, and creating them again in the same script , I need this script in my website for deleting all data from database (and I want to acces this script pressing one button on website) so I tried to do a function / procedure in PL/SQL that read line by line from the script file and executing every line with dynamic sql , everything went ok till one error at:

`CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER players_bir BEFORE INSERT ON players FOR EACH ROW BEGIN SELECT players_seq.NEXTVAL INTO :new.id FROM dual END`

this gave me the error:

> ORA-24344: success with compilation error

I searched for solutions, but I didn't find anything.

Comment: what does the error message for that trigger say in user_errors (or all_errors/dba_errors, depending on which user you're connected as)? That should give you a clue as to what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the semi-colon after dual on your SELECT statement.  This ORA error generally means you compiled some code, but that is has some issue.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER players_bir
  BEFORE INSERT ON players
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SELECT players_seq.nextval
    INTO :new.id
    FROM dual;
END
```

Looking in all_errors will show you what the issue is or you could manually compile this trigger in some IDE (like [SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html)) and that should also make it obvious.

```
SELECT *
  FROM all_errors e
 WHERE e.name = 'PLAYERS_BIR'
   AND e.type = 'TRIGGER';
```

Additionally if all you are using your trigger for is to set some identity column and you are on Oracle 12c you can use some of the [new features](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/identity-columns-in-oracle-12cr1) to accomplish this.  Triggers are inherently slow and the new identity feature performs about as good as referencing the sequence directly in your INSERT.